# Type 'void | RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader' is not assignable to type 'IUser[]'

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeerror

I have a `Users` class like following:

```
class Users {

  static async findAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) : Promise<IUser[]> {
    const rows = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users" )
      .then((rows) => {
      return rows[0];
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    next();
    return rows;

  }
}
```

But I get the error at the last line `return rows;` :

> Type 'void | RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket |
> OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader' is not assignable to type 'IUser[]'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IUser[]'.

This is the declaration of `IUser` interface:

import { RowDataPacket } from "mysql2"

```
interface IUser extends RowDataPacket {
  id?: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  username: string;
  admin: boolean;
  created_at: Date;
}

export {IUser};
```

I know the `rows[0]` is like  the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "admin@u.com",
    "password": "12345",
    "username": "admin@u.com",
    "admin": 1,
    "created_at": "2023-01-06T02:31:14.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "u@u.com",
    "password": "12345",
    "username": "u@u.com",
    "admin": 0,
    "created_at": "2023-01-06T03:08:20.000Z"
  }
]
```

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I found the correct solution but the error will gone by changing the following line:

```
const rows = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users" )
```

To:

```
const rows : any = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users" )
```